# SEO : what to do after url re writing

Tags: php, apache, url, url-rewriting, seo

I've made my php website url fiendly with url re-writting as,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ product.php?uni_id=$1 [NC,L] #
```

So, Old urls were,

```
http://example.com/product.php&uni_id=laptop-123
```

and new url is,

```
http://example.com/products/laptop-123/
```

Now, When search engine comes back they should informed about (old url is permenently moved to) new url or i can remove all entries from search engines in order to get rid of duplicate entries in search engines.

Now, what i have to do after writing url in terms of seo purpose.

NOTE : I've heard about using `301 redirects` but don't know how to implement it.

Comment: you have been misinformed, no Search engine cares what the url looks like

Comment: I mean in search engines new url should be replaced with old urls. so how to deal with duplicate urls ?

Comment: if the old url returns a 404 it will be removed, if the new url is linked anywhere it will be indexed .

Comment: No. Old urls does not returns 404. Both new and old urls are pointing to the same page.

Comment: in product.php check for the existence of uni_id, if it exists return a 404 or redirect to home page or what ever you want. this is why you should't of made any changes in the first place :-)

Comment: yes .. uni_id is there .. so ?

Comment: if it exists they are using the old url, so redirect

Comment: You could look at the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and if that is not the new style url, 301 redirect to there.

Comment: I was thinking `if(isset($_GET['uni_id'])){...}`

Answer (score 2):

To improve your SEO you should add canonical URLs.

You do that by adding a canonical url in the `head` of the page in question, so in your example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/products/laptop-123/">
```

That way for example Google knows which url to index and it will not penalize you for duplicate content.

Note that this is only one of the (easiest...) ways to achieve this, you could for example also do a 301 redirect when a visitor is not using your preferred url.

Also see the [information from Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) itself.

Comment: This is what i was thinking.